# create a pdf with a dynamic height based on length of the content using reportlab.platypus

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, reportlab

Am creating a sales receipt using reportlab in django rest framework. I want all the receipt contents to be in one page therefore the height should be dynamic based on the number of products purchased. The width is fixed which is 80mm. To design the receipt I set the height to 1000 pts to accommodate all contents in one page. [Here is the output of the receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkgrX.png).

This is the code that generates that receipt.

```
def generate_receipt_pdf(self, products_data, total_sales, cash_received, change, username):
        doc = BaseDocTemplate("sales_receipt.pdf", pagesize=portrait((226.08, 1000)), leftMargin=0,
                    rightMargin=0,
                    topMargin=14.17,
                    bottomMargin=0,)

        elements = []

        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        styles['Heading5'].fontName = 'Helvetica'
        styles['Heading5'].alignment = TA_CENTER
        styles['Heading5'].spaceAfter = 0
        styles['Heading5'].spaceBefore = 3

        elements.append(Paragraph("Denloy Investments", styles['Heading5']))
        elements.append(Paragraph("P.O. BOX 617", styles['Heading5']))
        elements.append(Paragraph("KERUGOYA", styles['Heading5']))

        styles['Heading5'].fontName = 'Helvetica-Bold'
        elements.append(Spacer(1, 6))
        elements.append(Paragraph("Sales Receipt", styles['Heading5']))
        elements.append(Spacer(1, 6))

        current_time = get_current_time()
        styles['Heading6'].fontName = 'Helvetica'
        elements.append(Paragraph(f"Date: {current_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')} {current_time.strftime('%I:%M %p')}", styles['Heading6']))
        elements.append(Paragraph(f"Cashier: {username.capitalize()}", styles['Heading6']))
        elements.append(Spacer(1, 6))

        styles['Normal'].fontSize = 7
        product_name_style = ParagraphStyle(
            name='product_name_style',
            fontName='Helvetica',
            fontSize=7,
            alignment=TA_LEFT,
            spaceAfter=0,
            spaceBefore=0,
        )

        # Convert products_data to a list of rows for the table
        table_data = [["Product Name", "Price", "", "Amount"]]
        for product in products_data:
            row = [Paragraph(product['product_name'], product_name_style), str(product['unitPrice']), f"x{str(product['units'])}", str(product['amount'])]
            table_data.append(row)

        spacer_row = ["", "--------------------", "", "---------"]
        table_data.append(spacer_row)
        total_row = ["", "Total", "", Paragraph(str(total_sales), styles['Normal'])]
        table_data.append(total_row)
        cash_row = ["", "Cash Received", "", Paragraph(str(cash_received), styles['Normal'])]
        table_data.append(cash_row)
        change_row = ["", "Change", "", Paragraph(str(change), styles['Normal'])]
        table_data.append(change_row)

        table = Table(table_data, colWidths=[116, 40, 20, 50])
        style = TableStyle([
            ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
            ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 1),
            ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 7),
            ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 1), (-1, -1), 0),
        ])

        table.setStyle(style)
        elements.append(table)

        styles['Normal'].alignment = TA_CENTER
        elements.append(Spacer(1, 6))
        elements.append(Paragraph("________________________________", styles['Normal']))
        elements.append(Paragraph("Thank you for shopping with us.", styles['Normal']))
        elements.append(Spacer(1, 6))

        page_frame = Frame(doc.leftMargin, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width, doc.height, id='normal')
        main_template = PageTemplate(frames=[page_frame])
        doc.addPageTemplates(main_template)

        doc.build(elements)
        with open("sales_receipt.pdf", "rb") as pdf_file:
            pdf_content = pdf_file.read()

        return pdf_content
```

After researching I tried setting the height to None, but it only takes float type, I also tried using KeepInFrame but it starts with an error of no attribute '_fontName' and just leads down a rabbitHole. Any way to create a pdf that has a dynamic height based on the content would be great.

Comment: @KJ Thanks that gave me an insight on the right direction.